# iOS NSURLSession handle the completion of a data task with a custom delegate

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios8

My end goal is to make http requests in the background while handling the response in memory. From my understanding, background requests have to be made with a custom delegate (which means I can't use `dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler)`), and to deal with the response in memory I have to use a data task (which means I can't use a download task along with `URLSession(session, downloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL)`).

According to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i-CH2-SW1 it doesn't look like there are any delegate methods that get called for data tasks upon completion. Is the only way to work with the response through a delegate to work with individual NSData fragments through `URLSession(session, dataTask, data)`? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDataDelegate/URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData: There's no delegate method for handling the entire final response as a single NSData instance?

Answer (score 3):

For small quantities of data like API calls or small images like avatars meant to be displayed immediately, `dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler)` is the method you want. It sets up an asynchronous task, meaning that when you start the task, execution will return to your code immediately and the task will take care of downloading the data and buffering it in memory "in the background" while your app is running. Once all the download task is complete, it  will call your completionHandler to let it know that it's done and that the data is ready. It will pass the data to your handler as an argument.

For larger files like podcasts, videos and large images, you'll want iOS to download the file for you even when the user starts looking at another app and your app is suspended. You will then want to use a [NSURLSessionDownloadTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSessionDownloadTask) with a background session configuration `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:` and a custom delegate. Your custom delegate will need to implement the method `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:`. When this method is called, you can read the contents of the file at the `url` that will be passed to you using code like this:

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
```

The reason background downloads that persist after an iOS app is quit are handled like this is that iOS wants to be able to continue downloading multiple files on behalf of different apps like podcasts, videos, etc. If the user is on a high speed network, downloading multiple large files in memory can quickly consume all of the devices memory, so they get stored as they are downloaded instead. In the same vein, you should keep your file sizes in mind before reading the entire file into memory with `NSData(contentsOfURL:)`.

Here's a working example of how everything fits together. Paste this in an iOS playground and look at the image you'll get:

```
import UIKit

class MyDelegate: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {
  func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: location) {
      // work with data ...
      UIImage(data: data)
    }
  }
}

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("my-session-identifier")
let delegate = MyDelegate()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: nil)
let url = NSURL(string: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/473550724433858560/tuHsaI2U.png")!
let task = session.downloadTaskWithURL(url)
task.resume()

// this allows the code to run in a playground
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: I was under the impression from Apple's documentation that you can't use `dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler)` if you want to handle a response in the background, you have to use a `NSURLSessionDelegate` which gets instantiated through your application lifecycle through some complicated process (haven't even gotten there yet...) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44

Comment: @user1084447 I misunderstood what you meant by in the background at first. I have expanded the answer to address iOS app backgrounding. Hope this answers it!

Comment: @hashemi no need to use NSData. you can use UIImage(contentsOfFile: location.path!)

Comment: @LeoDabus Correct. The OP wanted NSData so I didn't want to skip that step. UIImage is gravy.

Comment: Thanks @hashemi. The reason I wanted to try to keep the response in memory is because 1) I'm calling out to our own api and have control over the individual response sizes and will ensure they remain small; And 2) I'll be parsing the responses and updating a persistent SQLite store, so reading a file from disk just to update a SQLite store on disk sounds like wasted io to me... I found another piece of documentation which confirms that the only way to do this with a data task is to manually handle the fragments (only possible in ios8+). I'm going to try both methods and compare.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the docs you're supposed to implement the

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
```

method from `URLSessionTaskDelegate`. It "tells the delegate that the task finished transferring data" (per docs).
It will be called with `nil` value for `error`, but you also have to check `task.response` for potential problems.

Before that you should manually collect pieces of your data coming via the `URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:` calls:

> This delegate method may be called more than once, and each call provides only data received since the previous call. The app is responsible for accumulating this data if needed.

There's no delegate methods that would combine all the data into a single object for you, you have to do it manually.